# Best way to run Adobe Flash Player Projector?

Tags: wine, flash, adobe, swf

What's the best way to run the Flash Player Projector on Linux? Ruffle is not ideal since it doesn't work with ActionScript 3.

I tried the official Linux version from Adobe and the flatpak version, both are unusably glitchy.

I tried running the Windows .exe with wine, and it does work but... the LAG!

Is there a better way?

Edit: I found a better way, running the Windows exe through Bottles in gaming mode, it works and performs better than regular Wine.

Comment: Flash Player was discontinued by its maker many years ago. You are not going to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

im a bit late but another option is:
installing jpexs free flash decompiler you can go to the advanced settings-paths(or just click the play button by default and it will just bring you there if you havent set it up before) and they will have a waybackmachine link that allows you to see the original adobe downloads and get it.

while linux wont let you install it since it 'isnt supported' you can unpack the archive and use the player in the decompiler to play the flash no installation required.

was able to get my flash to run via this method

Answer (score 0):

The Best way I found to run Adobe Flash Player Projector is directly on Ubuntu OS.

**NOTE:** This software works very well on Ubuntu 20.04.6

Flash Player Projector for Ubuntu can be downloaded from here:

https://archive.org/download/adobe-flash-player-projector/flash_player_sa_linux.x86_64.tar.gz

The simplest way to extract and install this file is to click on "files" on your side panel, Navigate to the directory you downloaded to and then click on `flash_player_sa_linux.x86_64.tar.gz` to extract `flashplayer` to the directory of your choice.

You can run `flashplayer` from either the command line from the "files" side panel.

Flash Player Projector for Windows and other operating systems can be downloaded from here:

https://archive.org/details/adobe-flash-player-projector